# postgres backup with WAL

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, wal

i am in no way a db admin, so please don't shoot me if i'm doing it completly wrong ...

I have to add some archiving to a productive postgres database (newest version in docker container) and trying to build some scripts to use with WAL.

The idea is to have a weekly script, that does a full backup to a new directory and then creates a symlink to this new directory that is used by the WAL script to write it's logs. Also the weekly script will delete old backups older than 30 days.

I would be very happy for any comments on this...

db settings

```
wal_level = replica
archive_mode = on
archive_command = '/archive/archive_wal.sh "%p" "%f"'
archive_timeout = 300
```

weekly script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#create base archive dir
#base_arch_dir=/tmp/archive/
base_arch_dir=/archive/
if [ ! -d "$base_arch_dir" ]; then
  mkdir "$base_arch_dir"
  chown -R postgres:postgres "$base_arch_dir"
fi

#create dir for week
dir="$base_arch_dir"$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S')
if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
  mkdir "$dir"
  chown -R postgres:postgres "$dir"
fi

#change/create the symlink
newdir="$base_arch_dir"wals
ln -fsn "$dir" "$newdir"
chown -R postgres:postgres "$newdir"

#do the base backup to the wals dir
if pg_basebackup -D "$newdir" -F tar -R -X fetch -z -Z 9 -U postgres; then
  find "$base_arch_dir"* -type d -mtime +31|xargs rm -rf
fi
```

crchive script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

arch_dir=/archive/wals
arch_log="$arch_dir/arch.log"

if [ ! -d "$arch_dir" ]; then
  echo arch_dir '"$arch_dir"' does not exist >> "$arch_log"
  exit -1
fi

#get the variables from postgres
p=$1
f=$2

if [ -f "$arch_dir"/$f.xz ]; then 
  echo wal file '"$arch_dir"/$f.xz' already exists
  exit -1
fi

pxz -2 -z --keep -c $p > "$arch_dir"/$f.xz
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly difficult to put together your own archiving scripts, but there are a few things you need to keep track of, because when you need your backups you *really* need them. There are some packaged backup systems for PostgreSQL. You may find these two a good place to start, but others are available.

- https://www.pgbarman.org/
- https://pgbackrest.org/